# What does .NET developers need to know about these certain topics?

Tags: .net

I would like the SO community let me know what does juniors and proficient .NET Developers should know regarding the following subjects, also some code examples or brainteasers like the ones [here](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html) will help a lot.

- System Types
- Collection and Generics
- Configuration and Installation
- Monitoring and Debugging
- File I/O
- Globalization

Comment: This is really not what this site is for.

Comment: You might reword this question: "What do you think developers should know about these topics?"

Comment: Why not? Seem perfectly reasonable question. And, btw, why did you delete the "Thanks" at the end?

Comment: And make it community wiki. I think Dave's suggestion would make it a good question.

Comment: @muerte: It is not a programming question, it is a request for the community to mine data for him.

Comment: @Malfist: Community wiki does not mean what you seem to think it means.

Comment: @muerte - Removal is due to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468303/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed-on-stackoverflow/468725#468725

Comment: @RichB: There are a ton of questions like this on SO, and it's not just data mining. It's voting as well. I guess the idea is that the good interview questions get voted up. And again, thats one of the core ideas behind SO.

Comment: @LFSR Consulting, "Thanks" really isn't a tagline signature

Comment: @Muerte: Appealing to common practice is a logical fallacy that does not make this question anymore suitable for this site.

Comment: @Malfist: It is fluff, and is commonly eliminated from posts. Nothing new here, move on.

Comment: Questions appropriate for junior developers are not going to be suitable for proficient developers and vise versa.

Comment: @RichB: if it's common practice, then I guess that's what the site is for. I see absolutely nothing wrong with such a question, nor can i imagine a better site for it.

Comment: Uhm, guys who closed the question, what's the difference between this question and 10 other which are still open and listed on the right side, at the "related" section?

Comment: The difference is that this one came across the front page at a time when a group of 5 people with close rights saw it and decided it did not fit into what SO is focused on.

Comment: That is how community moderation works. If the members of the community that see it decide to close it, then it is closed.

Comment: Your question does make the case that these 5 mods should look at those other open questions and decide whether they should vote to close or not, however that would spend some of their few close votes for the day on questions that are not on the front page. They need those votes for ones that are.

Comment: this should be reopen since i doesnt violates stack overflow principles

Comment: It's not a bad question. It just lacks some focus.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70763/good-c-interview-questions-for-a-senior-dev-position

Comment: this is not for a senior position and its only for certain topics

Comment: Voted to close...not a real question. This isn't a discussion site.

Comment: "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion" I'd say this warrants an extended discussion, no?

Answer (score 4):

Another for generics.

What is the proper syntax (VB or C#) to require that the passed generic type be a type that implements a specific interface?

C# Example with an interface requirement of IHydratable

```
public static T HydrateObject<T>(IDataReader reader) where T : IHydratable
```

Answer (score 3):

> File I/O

How do you:

- Read a file's content
- What are file encodings... e.g. UTF-8.  Which encoding does .Net use internally? [Would not expect extensive detail, but should know not everything is ASCII]
- Why could the following code fail with a FileNotFoundException:

  ```
  if (File.Exists(name)) {
    var content = File.ReadAllText(name);
  }
  ```

> Globalization

- What is globalization?
- What does a globalised application not have. [Should know not to hardcode user display text, date/time/number/... formats]

Comment: For encodings: should also know which encoding .Net uses internally.

Comment: Never mind: needed to edit a spelling error, so I'll add that while I'm at it.

Comment: So why does the example about "File.Exists" fail? (Other than the obvious case of another thread deleting the file after the check but before the call to ReadAllText!)

Comment: @Hosam: Two reaons:  1) Because the file system is volatile and may change in between when you check and when you use it. 2) Just because a file exists doesn't mean you have permissions to access it.

Comment: [continued] The lessons is that because the file system is volatile, you have to be able to handle the exception when access to the file fails anyway, so making that exception handler work well is a much better place to put your development effort.

Comment: @Joel: yes, now for more difficult questions :-)

Comment: @Joel: The first reason is certainly true, but the second one doesn't seem so IMHO. According to the documentation of File.Exists: "If the caller does not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path."

Answer (score 2):

Let me start you off.

Generics:

What is the difference between an `ArrayList` and a `List<T>`? (Boxing/unboxing should come up here).

Comment: You gonna have to be a little more specific if you are looking for boxing. I suggest adding something like ' with regards to the item's type'. Fishing for a specific answer is not good.

Comment: No offense, but if someone cannot point out that ArrayList forces boxing/unboxing for value types and is therefore inferior to List<valuetype>... that's exactly the kind of red flag you are looking for with this question.

Answer (score 2):

On top of my head, for junior developers:

- Difference between method overriding and overloading
- Difference between namespace, class, assembly
- Value and reference type differences
- Explain boxing and how to avoid it

Answer (score 1):

Whats Wrong with the following code

```
struct MyStruct
{

   int _a;
   int _b;

   public MyStruct()
   {

   }

public MyStruct(int a,int b)
   {
        _a = a;
        _b = b;
   } 

}
```

Comment: You can't have a parameterless default constructor in a struct.